# Going to ground behind a Aegis defense line

Tags: warhammer-40k

If a unit goes to ground while behind an Aegis defense line (or some other "high" terrain), do we still consider them visible and potential targets for other shooting attacks?

After all, they're lying on the ground behind a wall.

Answer (score 2):

The same rules of true Line Of Sight apply regardless of gone-to-ground status.  We can assume the enemy has radios, some M41 version of IR scanners, etc and knows there's somebody there.

From a practical standpoint, it's just bad game balance/design to allow someone to shoot you without moving if you weren't able to shoot them on your turn.

Warhammer 40K is very much an abstract game played with pieces that look like soldiers.  It does not try to be a simulation.

Answer (score 1):

All fire is simultaneous so there is no other shooting all shot's will be take at the same time from a game point of view. We tend to do think unit by unit as that is how humans think best.

From the point of view of your unit they go to ground from being shot at in general not from being shot at from a specific unit, all they see is the bullets flying over head all at once.

This is why the true line of sight rules apply even after you have gone to ground as you would have gone to ground after every unit had taken aim.